# how to convert a string into a dictionary in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have data like following:

```
data = """
a:b,c,a
b:c,d
c:b
d:c
"""
```

I want to convert this string into a dictionary like this:

```
data_dict = {'a':['b','c','a'],'b':['c','d'],'c':['b'], 'd':['c']}
```

I tried:

```
data_list = data.strip('\n').split('\n')
data_str = ", ".join( repr(i) for i in data_list )
data_dict = {}

for i in range(len(data_list)):
    keys, values = data_list[i].split(':')
    key = keys.split('\t')
    value = values.split('\t')
    data_dict = dict(zip(key, value))
    print data_dict
```

But unfortunately, i got:

```
{'a':'b,c,a'}
{'b':'c,d'}
{'c':'b'} 
{'d':'c'}
```

Could anyone helps me out?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
>>> kvs = (line.split(":", 1) for line in data.strip().splitlines())
>>> d = {k: v.split(",") for k,v in kvs}
>>> d
{'a': ['b', 'c', 'a'], 'c': ['b'], 'b': ['c', 'd'], 'd': ['c']}
```